# How to make web2py dev server track file changes and restart automatically?

Tags: python, web2py

I used to work with Django and the way it's `runserver` restarts automatically whenever some python file is changed. That is really convenient and makes development easier for me.

Is there some way to tell `web2py` development server to track changes in python files and restart automatically?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is much easier in web2py and happens automatically. web2py model, controller, and view files are executed in a prepared environment on every request, so any updates to those files are reflected immediately without restarting anything. For modules that you import, you can do the following (typically in a model file):

```
from gluon.custom_import import track_changes
track_changes(True)
```

Any module that has changed since the last import will be reloaded.

Comment: Hi @Anthony, thank you for your answer. It actually works.Though I am not sure if it will fit my setup. There are many imported modules here and it's really tedious to add these line to every single imported file.

Comment: No, you don't add those lines to the imported modules -- you put the above lines in a *model* file (i.e., in the /models folder) -- and you only need it to appear once.

Comment: Oh, that's make things much easier. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I guess this will not always work, such as [this 2012 post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/tOoAzy3pAiU/cach5f8KFtYJ). I encounter similar problem right now. And I guess this is considered as too TRIVIAL to be fixed, because this reload module behavior is not recommended for production anyway. Just FYI.

Comment: I added these lines to a model file and it did not take effect until I restarted web2py once.  So make sure you restart web2py to reload the model files.  I also added these lines to my controller file before any of the other imports and it started working immediately within the controller file without requiring a restart of web2py.   Putting them in a model file and restarting web2py once is probably the best approach.